# Issues with AngularJS and IE10 routing.

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, angularjs, internet-explorer-10

Often when I quickly switch between different angular modules/controllers in IE10, the necessary routing will never take place.  I'm left with my page skeleton where no content has loaded and the index controller was never hit, but the angular module was defined.  The URL also indicates that no routing has occurred (no appended #/).  My module is defined as such with AngularJS 1.0.7:

```
angular.module('Users', ['ngResource', 'localization', 'pagination', 'resourceService']).
    config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/', {templateUrl: '../user/listAll.jsp',
            controller: ListUsersCtrl}).
        when('/edit/:userId', {templateUrl: '../user/edit.jsp',    controller: UserEditCtrl}).
        otherwise({redirectTo: '/'});
});

function ListUserCtrl($scope, $resource, $routeParams, $location, $timeout) {...}
function UserEditCtrl($scope, $resource, $routeParams, $location, $timeout) {...}
```

Again, this works fine most of the time, it's only about every 9th or 10th page reload that no routing will take place.  Does anyone have any thoughts or suggestions as to why this may be happening?  It may be present in older versions of IE but I can't confirm that.

Comment: How are you switching modules/controllers?

Comment: @moderndegree yes.  No luck.  Any other advice?

Comment: I had this exact same issue.  Manually bootstrapping resolved it for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem, solved it by forcing IE10 to IE9 Compatibility mode.

Add this to your html head:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">
```

Comment: I feel uncomfortable with this solution, but it did fix my buggy routing in IE10.

Comment: I have similar problems with IE 11 as well. Strangely but it happens only with IE 10 and 11. Forcing IE9 compatibility helps temporarily resolving the issue until MS fixes its bugs.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding query string to force IE, eg:

```
<a ng-href="/test.aspx#/?iefix">Test</a>
```

Worked for me in IE11.